# Terraform, AWS cron syntax

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I can't figure out what's wrong with my cron. This is the terraform plan

```
  + aws_autoscaling_schedule.web_wkday_5am_et
      id:                     <computed>
      arn:                    <computed>
      autoscaling_group_name: "web"
      desired_capacity:       "175"
      end_time:               <computed>
      max_size:               "250"
      min_size:               "175"
      recurrence:             "0 9 ? * 1-5"
      scheduled_action_name:  "WEB WKDAY 5AM ET"
      start_time:             <computed>
```

i've tried the following to no luck

```
0 9 ? * MON-FRI *
0 9 ? * MON-FRI
0 9 ? * 1-5
```

Not sure if this is a TF issue or AWS. I'm following this doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You require the following:

```
recurrence = "cron(0 9 ? * MON-FRI *)"
```

You are missing cron function wrapping your expression.

Answer (score 1):

Just because I saw that you are using an scheduled action on an AWS ASG, I got it to work using this:

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_schedule" "scale-down" {
  scheduled_action_name  = "scale-down"
  min_size               = 0
  max_size               = 0
  desired_capacity       = 0
  recurrence             = "0 20 * * *"
  autoscaling_group_name = module.asg.this_autoscaling_group_name
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_schedule" "scale-up" {
  scheduled_action_name  = "scale-up"
  min_size               = 1
  max_size               = 1
  desired_capacity       = 1
  recurrence             = "0 8 * * MON-FRI"
  autoscaling_group_name = module.asg.this_autoscaling_group_name
}
```

aws using their own cron syntax is a nightmare(it's only 5 entries).